# How can I add a new audio track to an x265 MP4 video without re-encoding it?

Tags: audio, mp4, video-encoding

I would've tried MKVMerge or MakeMKV but they won't work on MP4 files. Does anyone have a way to just add the track? Cause adding it via Handbrake or something would take too much time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html), a free command-line tool.

Syntax would be

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -c copy -map 0 -map -0:d -map 1 new.mp4
```

Comment: "[mp4 @ 00000000024c2040] Could not find tag for codec bin_data in stream #2, codec not currently supported in container
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument"

Are you sure this works on x265 files? Or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Share the full console output.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/1Q4WG4YK

Comment: Are there subtitles in the original file?

Comment: Yes it's a useless subtitle file muxed in there. I don't need it

Comment: See edited cmd.

Comment: It worked, thank you. That didn't take any time and the new file works perfectly.